# Opamp filter cutoff frequency not as expected at higher frequencies

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, frequency

I'm still working on learning Butterworth filters.  So far this weekend I went back to school, read about Lapace transforms, poles and zeros, Saleen key design, and finally back to Butterworth filters again.  I've been working on understanding this TI app note:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa049b/sloa049b.pdf

I followed the math for their example in section 10 and then spiced it and I saw the -3dB was 1Khz like it says.  So then I tried to design the same filter with a cutoff of 5Mhz, but instead of -3dB down it was around -6dB down.   Then I tried to build a 5Khz filter to check my math and this one was -3dB at 5Khz.   I'm using a TI OPA355, and was looking through the datasheet but all the charts make me think it's good to at least 200Mhz.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what, I suspect it has to do with the performance of the opamp, and something I don't know to look for or calculate from the datasheet?

Here's my circuit:

[image]

Comment: Did you take the input pin capacitance into account ?
According to the datasheet the input capacitance is about 1.5pf.

Comment: Why unsymmetric power supply (+2.5/-1.5volts)? Did you watch the slew rate limitations?

Comment: With respect to Mike`s comment: Increase the capacitors by a factor of 10 and reduce all resistor values also by this factor. Try again.

Comment: That did work, well it got to about 3.5dB.  I get that there is input capacitance but how do I take that into account when I'm calculating my RC values?

Comment: I think I get it, I added 1.5pf to C1 and calculated fc.  It matched the 3dB point.

Comment: Can someone write this into an answer? I think it's a great question and covers things that are sometimes hidden such as the parasitics

Comment: I built a spreadsheet to calculate all of the values for each stage, but my final stage rings really high.  Is there something else like output and input impedance I should be taking into account for each stage?